# Eliminar una linea de un txt en python por la posición que este ocupa dentro del txt y no por el contenido

Tags: python, tkinter, txt

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente txt
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, lo que deseo es realizar una aplicación que yo pueda borrar mediante la ejecución de un botón y un text box la línea que contenga cierta pocisión dentro del txt. Para que se entienda en el text box yo declararía la posicion de la línea, por ejemplo, si quiero eliminar la línea de `azul jose arias alto grande` pondría 0 en el text box y le daría al boton y la línea de rojo subiría a esa posición, para el caso de querer borrar `rojo marlon perez` etc pondría 1 y le daría al boton. No sé si me explico lo que quiero es borar todo el contenido de la línea por su posición y que la que viene debajo ocupe la pocisión de la borrada y así sucesivamente. Lo que he logarado hasta ahora es esto pero no me funciona

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



raiz =Tk()
raiz.title("hello")
raiz.geometry("1000x500")
raiz.config(bg ="gray")
raiz.config(bd="30")
raiz.config(relief="groove")
miframe = Frame(raiz,bg="white",width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill ="both",expand = "True")

borrar_cliente = StringVar()
textocliente=Entry(miframe,textvariable=borrar_cliente,width="30")
textocliente.grid(row="10",column="1")


def borrar():
    f = open("x.txt", "r")
    lineas = f.readlines()
    print(lineas)
    f.close()

    f = open("x.txt", "w")
    for linea in lineas:
        if linea != borrar_cliente.get()+ "\n":
            print(borrar_cliente.get())
            f.write(linea)
    f.close()
borrar_client =Button(miframe,text="borrar",command =borrar, relief="raised", borderwidth=5)
borrar_client.place(x=720, y=10)



raiz.mainloop()
```

Necesito que `borrar_cliente.get()` sea la pocisión de la línea dentro del txt. Aclarar que los espacios entre `azul jose arias` etc son espacios de tabulador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error que tienes se encuentra en la función `borrar()`. Te explico:

Para empezar, veamos cada parte de tu función.

```
def borrar():
    f = open("x.txt", "r")
    lineas = f.readlines()
    print(lineas)
    f.close()
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. Tienes una lista `lineas` con todas las lineas de tu documento de texto `x.txt`. Pero analicemos el **for**:

```
    f = open("x.txt", "w")
    for linea in lineas:
        if linea != borrar_cliente.get()+ "\n":
            print(borrar_cliente.get())
            f.write(linea)
    f.close()
```

Entiendo que quieres eliminar la línea que se ingresa por el frame del tkinter, pero eso no es lo que está sucediendo aquí. Lo que hace este **for** es un recorrido por cada línea; con la condición de que si esa línea es diferente a "la posición más `'\n'`", se escribirá en el documento.

Ahora analicemos con un ejemplo lo que se ha hecho aquí. Supongamos que quieres borrar la primera línea. El código sería algo así:

```
    for linea in lineas:
        if linea != "0" + "\n": #En el primer recorrido linea='azul jose arias alto grande'
            f.write(linea)      #Como sí es diferente, se escribe esa línea en el documento
    f.close()
```

Y en el segundo recorrido del **for** se escribirá la siguiente línea  porque **siempre** serán diferentes a `"0\n"`

Entonces, ¿Cómo se soluciona eso? Tengo entendido que quieres que el valor de `borrar_cliente.get()` sea la posición de la línea que quieres eliminar. Para eso, sólo basta crear una variable `pos` e ingresarle el valor como entero (ya que lo que te entrega el frame es un `str`). Con esa posición, ya se puede ubicar la posición de la línea con `lineas[pos]`. Después de eso, simplemente se elimina con la función `lineas.remove()`.

En ese punto ya se tendría la lista `lineas` con la línea eliminada. Solo bastaría con hacer un recorrido con un **for** para escribir cada línea en el documento de texto. El código solucionado quedaría algo así:

```
    pos=int(borrar_cliente.get())
    linea=lineas[pos]
    lineas.remove(linea)
    for linea in lineas:
        f.write(linea)
    f.close()
```

#### Código arreglado completo de la función:

```
def borrar():
    f = open("x.txt", "r")
    lineas = f.readlines()
    print(lineas)
    f.close()
    
    f = open("x.txt", "w")
    
    pos=int(borrar_cliente.get())
    linea=lineas[pos]
    lineas.remove(linea)
    for linea in lineas:
        f.write(linea)
    f.close()
```

Comment: gracias eres un genio

Comment: gracias ,pero tengo una pregunta para ti como podemos observar en el txt solo hay dos valores posibles para borrar,,el valor 0 y el valor 1 por que tiene solo dos lineas,si pongo un 2 en el entry y doy al boton   me da un error y me borra el txt entero,,el error que daria seria este ,,IndexError: list index out of range,,como yo podria limitar la entrada del entry a la cantidad reales de lineas del txt,,,,lo que pido es que para este caso por ejmeplo solo yo pueda introducir el valor 0 y 1 en el entry por que el txt solo tiene 2 lineas,y en caso de que quere introducir 2 o3 o 4,etc no me deje

Comment: Hay varias formas para hacer eso... la más accesible en este caso sería crear una condicional en la funcion `borrar`. Pondría algo como: `if borrar_cliente.get() > len(lineas):`; en este caso, si lo que ingresa el usuario es mayor a la cantidad de lineas, colocaría un mensaje diciendo ha ingresado un valor invalido. De caso contrario, haría lo demás (lo que está en la función actualmente).

Comment: Si te ayudó mi respuesta. No olvide marcar como mejor respuesta ;)

Comment: Excelente!!! ¿Me podríais ayudar con algo? si para el caso de arriba propuesto quisiera cambiar las lineas por otras de otro archivo de texto/archivo de forma aleatoria //lineas completas? ¿Seria muy difícil?